# Stop on going download on button click android

Tags: android, service, download, intentservice

I am developing an application, which focus mainly on downloading a file from web service and storing it in sd card. Everything went easy until my client needs to cancel the on going download. I tried many ways but i failed. So can any one help me out and post some snippets for cancelling on going download. Intent service will be much preferred.

Edit:

```
                    Toast.makeText(ThumbnailView.this, R.string.Download_start, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    info_icon.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    langBtn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    name.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE );
                    author.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE );
                    lastReading.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    intent = new Intent(ThumbnailView.this,
                        DownloadAndExtractFiles.class);
                    Common.isDownloadProgress = true;
                intent.putExtra("BEAN", bean);
                intent.putExtra("FROM", "library");
                intent.putExtra("receiverTag", mReceiver);
                startService(intent);
```

IntentService Class:

```
            try {

                File file = new File(path, /* BOOK_ID */filename + fileformat);
                if (file.exists())
                    file.delete();
                file.createNewFile();
                output = new FileOutputStream(file);

                finalpath = path + "/" + filename + fileformat;

                Log.d("book UNEXTR path", finalpath);
                byte data[] = new byte[1024];
                long total = 0;


                while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                    if (Common.downloadChkLogout) {
                        // Changed on saturday 9th nov
                        //if (Common.isDownloadProgress) {
                            if (stopped) {
                                break;
                            }
                            total += count;
                            Bundle resultData = new Bundle();
                            resultData.putInt("progress",
                                    (int) (total * 100 / lenghtOfFile));
                            bean.setProgress((int) (total * 100 / lenghtOfFile));
                            rec.send(UPDATE_PROGRESS, resultData);
                            output.write(data, 0, count);
                        }
                    }
                success = true;
                //}
                output.flush();
                output.close();
                input.close();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                mError = "Download Failed";
                System.out.println("Net Disconnect;:" + mError);

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), mError,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
```

Edit:

```
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
 Log.i("Aftr before service stopped---->>>>>", "true"); 
 Log.i("Intent obj","Intent check..."+intent);
 if(intent!=null)
{ 
 Common.isDownloadProgress = false;
 stopService(intent);
```

This is my cancel click

I have posted my code for starting the service, and downloading part on onHandleIntent
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Are you downloading the file in `AsyncTask`?

Comment: @Apoorv Nope. I am using IntentService.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to check whether it's stopped or not from within your service and you are half done on that line

```
if (stopped)
    break;
```

now make `stopped` a static boolean and set it to true on button click,

**Edit**
You are already checks `Common.isDowloadProgress` but it's commented and I believe you need to break the loop as follows

```
while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1)
{
    if (Common.downloadChkLogout)
    {
        if (Common.isDownloadProgress)
        {
            if (stopped)
            {   break;   }
            total += count;
            Bundle resultData = new Bundle();
            resultData.putInt("progress",
                   (int) (total * 100 / lenghtOfFile));
            bean.setProgress((int) (total * 100 / lenghtOfFile));
            rec.send(UPDATE_PROGRESS, resultData);
            output.write(data, 0, count);
        }
        else
        {    break;   }
    }
}
success = true;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am setting stopped - true in onDestroy method. Because once we call stopservice automatically onDestroy will be called.   public void onDestroy() {
   Log.i("Inside Intent Service onDestroy->", "true");
   String notice;
   
   stopped = true; }

Comment: does't it work? if not post your onClick implementation as edit

Comment: public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
         Log.i("Aftr before service stopped---->>>>>", "true");
         
         Log.i("Intent obj","Intent check..."+intent);
          if(intent!=null){
          Common.isDownloadProgress = false;
          
          
          
           stopService(intent);

Comment: i have added.. plz check

Answer (score 0):

I thing you should use AsyncTask for downloading items, It porvide on cancel event as well.

Let say you are using HttpGet to download you file, your task will look like...

```
public class FileDownloadingTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    private String url = null;
    private String destPath = null;
    private HttpGet httpGet = null;
    // Constructor
    public FileDownloadingTask(String url, String destPath) {
        this.url = url;
        this.destPath = destPath;
    }

    // Create a progress dialog in your onPreExecute

    // Start downloading in your doInBackground and save to destPath in sd-card

    // Proform any thing your want in response to download process in onPostCreate

    // Finally...
    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
        super.onCancelled();
        // Aborting http request
        if (httpget != null) {
            httpget.abort();
        }
    }

    // Then in your cancel button of progress dialog call this.onCancel();
}
```

Hope this will give you some hint...:)

Answer (score 0):

Add this on your button click. Modify the if condition to suit your needs. I am uploading a video and when i click on remove, this happens :-

```
              if(processFileUploadTask !=null && processFileUploadTask.getStatus() != AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED){

                Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {

                        if(httpost != null ){
                            httpost.abort();
                        }

                    }
                });
                t.start();
```